# HTML inside PHP is shown as plain text in email

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to put html into php for emailing.The first time I tried directly entering the html into the variable (php double quotes and html in single quotes) but that resulted in an internal error. Then I used the <<< function and pasted the html insided (proper use of indentation). Now when I receive the email, i get the html file returned in plain text. How do I go from here?

```
    $mailer->Body = <<<DEMO
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
........
</tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>


DEMO;
```

Comment: are you sending the right mail headers `$headers.= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";`

Comment: You should echo your html code or close  php with `?>` enter your html code then if you want open php tag again using `<?php`

Comment: @nogad  How would I implement that in this code?

Comment: based on the code provided - no idea

Comment: @nogad because I already provided that definition:  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

Comment: no thats the email body, you still have to send the header - which will tell the client to expect html vs plain text. its going to depend on your $mailer class.

Comment: A good question must be completed with the relevant code, and not just a few lines of them. This will help everyone which is try to help, Avoiding long rows of comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you're using plain php:

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

you need to add this to the headers:

```
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
```